# What danger can come from D-DoS over VPN

Tags: vpn, ddos

Every time I use VPN, I get a message to notify me to be sure that my PC is 'healthy' from pots infections. Also I've read in [this article](https://ghostbin.com/paste/jrr89) to stay away from that.

My question, what damage could happen to my system & network if I ignored that warning? and most important, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "document" says that you should stay away from DoS tools because it is easy to get caught by the target site. DoS'ing through a VPN server is even more "dangerous" as the VPN server will know it was you who made the mess and THEY HAVE YOUR INFO.

**So, follow the chain of events:**

1. You connect to the VPN server.
2. You start the DoS attack.
3. The attacked website ackowledges the attack
4. The attacked website calls the police
5. The police busts at the VPN server
6. The VPN server's admin crew find you in their logs
7. The VPN server's admin crew give your IP address AND registration
   information to the police
8. You get busted.

**Or it may even be a closer version:**

1. You connect to the VPN server.
2. You start the DoS attack.
3. The VPN server's admin crew ackowledges the attack
4. The VPN server's admin crew calls the police
5. You get busted.

Comment: so the VPN provider is concerned only about me  not get busted? I think there are more reasons especially to harm their networks.

Comment: I really don't know any country where the VPN provider is not obliged by law to call the local/federal law enforcer if they sense an attack. So, if you are consuming a huge portion of their bandwidth or not, they still have to call the cops. And calling the cops doesn't mean they won't take further actions on their own part.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all you have to consider that by using a VPN you are implicitly trusting the other end of the communication, as all your data will be sent there.

This exposes you to MiM attacks, as the VPN server will, by definition, be a server in the middle of your communication. For example, all your HTTP traffic can be eavesdropped, and your packets might be modified by the remote server without your knowledge (this is a broad and different topic as it depends on several factors however).

There are also chances that your VPN provider **uses you as a VPN endpoint**. Several free VPN servers do this (bandwith costs money). The problem is that you might be re-routing traffic from someone doing *evil* things through the VPN.

If you want more information on this topic, I would refer you to [this page](http://www.personalvpn.org/#!proxy-servers/u45xj)